# Android replace fragment still displays some of the replaced fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a tab that contains a linear layout with a searchview and a listview. When the user clicks one of the search results, I want to replace that layout with another layout containing the details of the selection.

What happens when I replace the search fragment only the listview portion of the layout gets replaced; the searchview is still visible and active on the screen.

Here is my search layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/search_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <SearchView
        android:id="@+id/public_calendar_search"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
    </SearchView>

    <ListView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@android:id/empty"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the detail layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/detail_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Space
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="20dip"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Space
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".1" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".8"
            android:text="@string/label_Name" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".1" />
    </LinearLayout>

    .........

</LinearLayout>
```

And my code to replace the search fragment:

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

// Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
// and add the transaction to the back stack.
DetailFragment fragment = DetailFragment.newInstance(cal);
transaction.replace(R.id.search_layout, fragment);

transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.commit();
```

Detail fragment creation:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.detail_layout, container, false);
    return v;
}

static DetailFragment newInstance(String cal) {
    DetailFragment d = new DetailFragment();
    return d;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?  How can I get the entire search layout to be replaced.

Thanks!

Comment: You are not showing how the DetailFragment sets up its layout

Comment: Heiko, I added that information...

Comment: so are you trying to remove your original search tab or are you trying to place a layout over it temporarily to show your search results??

Comment: The latter.  I want to replace the search fragment (which contains both the searchview and the listview) with the details fragment. The user would then return to the search fragment after viewing and/or acting on the details fragment.

This is working - almost. When the details fragment is displayed, the searchview from the search fragment is still visible (and functional). 

In debugging, I added a textview both before and after the searchview to see what happens. In this case, both textviews and the searchview remain visible with the detail fragment is displayed.

Comment: Have you considered instead adding the detailsfragment on top of everything and using a different tag for it. For example,
DetailFragment fragment = DetailFragment.newInstance(cal);
transaction.add(android.R.id.content, fragment,"MyDetailsTaG");
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.commit();

Comment: I did post an answer for the problem same like this here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63683045/8874958

Answer (score 18):

I figured out my problem. Marco wasn't exactly right but he pointed me in the right direction.

The problem was the the container ID I was passing to the replace method was the ID of the fragment I was replacing, not the ID of the fragment container. This seems to explain why some of the original fragment controls were remaining after the replace - that entire fragment wasn't being replaced.

I changed it to get the fragment container view ID, and that worked! Here's the code:

```
transaction.replace(((ViewGroup)(getView().getParent())).getId(), fragment);
```

I found the answer for getting the container view ID of a fragment here, [Get fragment's container view id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6925941/get-fragments-container-view-id).

Comment: +1 This line point to what view `((ViewGroup)(getView().getParent())).getId()` Please help

Comment: This line point to what view ((ViewGroup)(getView().getParent())).getId() Please help –

Comment: This still does not solve my problem. I can still see my older fragment.

Answer (score 12):

I was using the correct ID, then also it wasnt going away. Turns out that you need to set the `Background color` to your needed color in new Fragment layout, like this.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="@color/white_color">
```

Answer (score 6):

To solve the problem, set the android:background property to “?android:windowBackground” in the fragment layout files.

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="?android:windowBackground"
    tools:context=".MainFragment">

    ...

</LinearLayout>
```

In Fragment_2

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="?android:windowBackground"
    tools:context=".SomeFragment">

    ...

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem, and the solution didn't work for me. Maybe this will help someone...

I had added a fragment inside the activity layout xml file. This caused a lot of issues.

Instead, add a frame layout in your xml file, and then programatically add and replace fragments. This causes the whole fragment to be replaced.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem once, and this is my solution.
Try to do this, use `FrameLayout` instead of `fragment` in your layout file. Just like this:

```
    <fragment android:id="@+id/your_fragment" />
```

Then, add your default fragment in activity method `onCreate()`.

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
.add(R.id.your_fragment, YourFragment)
.commit();
```

Now, the old fragment can be replaced correctly, it looks great.

This worked for me, and I hope it helps you too.