# Previous fragment visible under the new fragment

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-viewpager

I have a tab  + `ViewPager` layout and in one of these tabs I have a list view.  When I replace that list fragment upon the onclick I can still see the old fragment under the new fragment.  See:

[image]

**Code:**

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
HallsInStateFragment hallsForState = new HallsInStateFragment();        
transaction.replace(R.id.container, hallsForState);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.commit();
```

where the `R.id.container` is the FrameLayout in the view.

Comment: try giving a bg color to the fragment containing layout

Comment: Nobody can help you if you don't provide the code you used. Also, please don't prefix your question's title with Android, the tag at the bottom is enough.

Comment: Make sure you're not calling FragmentTransaction.add() when you should be calling FragmentTransaction.replace().

Comment: @Krylez I am using FragmentTransaction.replace()

Comment: @Luksprog I have added the code, sorry wasn't at computer when posted

Comment: Hi @SquiresSquire am facing the same problem. Did you got any solution for this ?

Comment: I know it's too late but this answer can help others [http://stackoverflow.com/a/37299088/4183013](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37299088/4183013)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of R.id.container put id of fragment like this: `((ViewGroup)getView().getParent()).getId()`. Actually it is not replacing the fragment but the previous layout i.e FrameLayout. It works for me and i hope it will work in your case also.

Comment: getview method not defined

Comment: getView().getParent()).getId() no method as such. please follow link to achieve:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16643167/previous-fragment-visible-under-the-new-fragment/42113563#42113563

Answer (score 13):

when need to remove all views from the parent view you need to call **removeAllViews()** at container in your **onCreateView()** method of your fragment.

Here is the code:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

container.removeAllViews(); // Inflate the layout for this fragment
 return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_example, container, false); 
}
```

Comment: This question is over 3 years old, and has already been solved

Comment: if i use container.removeAllViews(); when i press back from 2nd fragment, 1st fragment wont be visible. Obviously, its been cleared. But how do i retain 1st fragment on backpress yet achieve clean 2nd fragment ?

Comment: Accepted answer doesn't appear to be a valid function call and this works great if you aren't relying on a backstack history. Things change and so it's great to see updated answers so we don't have to create duplicate questions as Android evolves over time. Thanks taranjeetsapra!

Answer (score 5):

Add this to both fragment parent layout

`android:background="@android:color/white"`.

The one which you are replacing and one which you will replace.

Comment: This answer only hides the old fragment. Use can still make click events in old fragment.
For disabling this as well add ` clickable = true` in root-view

Answer (score 2):

The fragment's UI is a part of the activity view hierarchy. So if you created your views in onCreateView() method then you inflate your layout using the ViewGroup container. This container keeps references to your fragment views. Try to override onDestroyView() method of your fragment and  remove all the views from the parent:

```
@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    //mContainer.removeAllViews();
    ViewGroup mContainer = (ViewGroup) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.container);
    mContainer.removeAllViews();
    super.onDestroyView();
}
```

Comment: Fragment should not manage parent, it's the parent responsibility to manage its childs.

Comment: This did not work for me, however @taranjeetsapra 's answer below seems to be working so far

Answer (score 1):

Your fragments should be loaded in `FrameLayout` like this

```
    <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="?android:windowBackground" />
```

And your fragments should be added/loaded in this `frameLayout` by this function

```
    private fun switchFragment(
    fragment: Fragment,
    addToBackstack: Boolean
) {
    //check new fragment is alredy loaded currently, then return
    val myFragment =
        supportFragmentManager.fragments.lastOrNull()//return current visible fragment or null
    if (myFragment != null && fragment::class == myFragment::class) {
        return
    }

    val fragmentManager = supportFragmentManager
    val transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    //transaction.add(R.id.frameLayout, fragment, fragment.javaClass.name)
    transaction.replace(
        R.id.frameLayout,
        fragment,
        fragment.javaClass.name
    )//using replace will make sure that the previous fragment won't be visible from new fragment
    if (addToBackstack) {
        transaction.addToBackStack(fragment.javaClass.name)
    }
    transaction.commit()
}
```

So initially, your first fragment should be loaded like this,

```
switchFragment(HomeFragment(), false)
```

and then other fragments when you select from bottom navigation view or navigation drawer, call this function like this

```
switchFragment(MyProfileFragment(), true)
```

Answer (score 1):

In My Case , This was happening because I was using the static fragment as

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<fragment
    android:name="com.example.android.FooFragment"
    android:id="@+id/fooFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

where foofragment is the initial fragment , Then Trying to replace the fragment using with other fragment , so that both fragment overlaps.

Instead , Problem is solved , when I used dynamic Linkage , in place of fragment in the xml , we need to use framelayout as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

  <FrameLayout
       android:id="@+id/your_placeholder"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent">
  </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Then dynamically adding the fragment-1 and replacing with the fragment-2 , is working fine for me.

```
I did not find answer earlier, hence posting this solution.
```

Answer (score 0):

In the root view add `clickable = true` and add a background color(both in the xml) of the fragment replacing the current fragment .
Its just a fix for workaround

Answer (score 0):

Best code for it. clearly and not used another ram of device.
on you Activity onCreate or before adding fragments add this code:

```
for (Fragment fragment : getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments()) {
    if (fragment instanceof NavigationDrawerFragment) {
        continue;
    }
    else if (fragment != null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(fragment).commit();
    }
}
```

**Happy coding :)**