# Previous fragment visible below new fragment

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I have a TabLayout with a ViewPager. The ViewPager have four fragments F1, F2, F3 and F4. F1 contains a FrameLayout which can have 2 fragments F11 and F12. Initially I add F11 in the FrameLayout with below code.

```
Fragment11 fragment11 = new Fragment11();
fragment11.setArguments(getActivity().getIntent().getExtras());
getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment11, Constants.FRAGMENT_11)
                .commit();
```

F11 contains a ListView. When I click on any item/row in this ListView then F11 is replaced with F12. F12 is a detail fragment.

```
Fragment12 fragment12 = new Fragment12();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment12, Constants.FRAGMENT_12)
                    .addToBackStack(null)
                    .commit();
```

For normal app flow it works fine. Now suppose currently I am in Fragment12 and I pressed home button. Now I open any heavy application (camera or any other app) to remove my app from memory. Now I started my app again.

Now there are two Fragment11 and one Fragment12 are visible, all at the same time. When I press back Fragment12 is removed and now two Fragment11 are visible. When I click the ListView row of Fragment11 then the top Fragment11 is replaced with Fragment12, however, the bottom Fragment11 remains there.

This is what I want:
When the app comes to the foreground from background then Fragment12 should be visible and when I press back Fragment12 should be popped to show Fragment11.

How can I do this?

Comment: You may want to use the proper FragmentManager, getChildFragmentManager(),  when adding those two nested fragments.

Comment: @Luksprog If I use getChildFragmentManager() instead, I couldn't find R.id.fragment_container. Its giving exception. java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0e014c (com.demo:id/fragment_container) for fragment Fragment12

Comment: If those fragments are used inside the layout of another fragment then you need to use the getChildFragmentManager(). If you get that error you're doing something wrong in your code/layout. You didn't posted much code but another question is if you have **checks** for F11 and F12 being available in the getChildFragmentManager() before you're adding them to the layout(or you're blindly adding those fragments whenever an instance of the parent is constructed) with the current code?

Answer (score 10):

I know it's too late but this answer can help others. it's not a proper solution but it's working for me. So put `android:clickable="true"` and `android:background="?android:attr/colorBackground"` in the root view of your fragment. hope this will work.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem. But I also could not find a proper solution for this. In my scenario when I open multiple apps and them come back to my app it causes the same issue with Fragments that happen on your side. But I made my app stable. I have done this by the following solution:

1. When your app remove from memory then again open the app then onCreate() method called of your MainActivity in which you are showing Fragments.
2. Here I checked the backstackEntrycount and if it is greater then 0, then remove all fragments and show the base fragment.

   ```
   // Clear all fragments and show base fragment, So it will not create
   // issue after opening
   // multiple apps
   FrameLayout flSliding = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.fl_sliding);
   flSliding.post(new Runnable() {

       @Override
       public void run() {
           FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
           Log.i("NavigationDrawerActivity",
                   "onCreate " + fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount());
           if (fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
               removeFragment(fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount());
           }
           Log.i("NavigationDrawerActivity",
                   "onCreate " + fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount());
       }
   });
   ```

Hope it will help!

Comment: Above code didn't helped me. When the app is again started then three fragments F11, F11 and F12 are visible. When I used your code then two fragments are visible, F11 and F11. I don't understand what is happening. Same thing is resolved by Gmail app. Gmail have two fragments, list of mails and detail mail. When I close the app from detail fragment then after coming to the app again shows detail fragment and not list of emails. How did they handled this?