# View controls remain after listfragment is replaced by nested fragment

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-listfragment

I have a tabbed view activity with 3 tabs and one fragment in each tab. Those fragments are managed by a `FragmentPageAdapter` linked to a viewpager.

Everything works fine until I try to have a 4th fragment (**ServiceSpecifNotListFragment**) that would be a nested fragment of one of the fragments (*ServicesListFragment*) managed by the `FragmentPageAdapter`.

When I try to replace the *ServicesListFragment* by the **ServiceSpecifNotListFragment**. I manage to replace only the list element from *ServicesListFragment* by the **ServiceSpecifNotListFragment**, the other view controller (a button) from *ServicesListFragment* remains....

I have been wondering if the problem lies in the fact that the method I use to replace the fragment by its subfragment is `transaction.replace(R.id.service_list_fragment, newFragment).commit();` and **service_list_fragment** is the id of the listfragment main linear layout which contains the listview defined with the id: `@id/android:list`

The closest Q&A I found to this was [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12958555/android-replace-fragment-still-displays-some-of-the-replaced-fragment) but as far as I understood I am using the fragment container id correctly.

Here is the code and layout:

Layout of *ServicesListFragment* (the parent of the nested fragment)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:orientation="vertical"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:id="@+id/service_list_fragment">

      <Button
      android:id="@+id/addServiceButton"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="AddService" />

     <ListView android:id="@id/android:list"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="0dip"
               android:layout_weight="1"
               android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"/>

     <TextView android:id="@id/android:empty"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:text="No data"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Layout of **ServiceSpecifNotListFragment**(the fragment to be nested)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:orientation="vertical"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:id="@+id/service_notif_list_fragment" >    
     <ListView android:id="@id/android:list"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="0dip"
               android:layout_weight="1"
               android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"/>

     <TextView android:id="@id/android:empty"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:text="No data"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Main activity xml layout (it is basically a reference to the pager):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

Source code of ServiceListFragment, the call for the nesting of fragments is in the `onListItemClick` :

```java
public class ServicesListFragment extends ListFragment  {

    private final String TAG = "ServicesListFragment";
    Button addButton = null;

    ServiceNotifRowAdapter adapter;
    ArrayList<NotifService> list = new ArrayList<NotifService>();


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Activity parent = getActivity();

        // some ommited code for populating adapter with list of stored subscriptions
            adapter = new ServiceNotifRowAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),list);
        setListAdapter(adapter);

    }

      @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.servicelist_fragment, container, false);

            addButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.addServiceButton);
            MainActivity m = (MainActivity) getActivity();
            addButton.setOnClickListener(m);
            return rootView;
        }

      @Override
      public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

          NotifService  item = (NotifService) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
          Log.d(TAG, "selected service " + item.getServiceURI());


        Fragment newFragment = new ServiceSpecifNotListFragment();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("service", item.getServiceURI());
        newFragment.setArguments(bundle);
                FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                transaction.replace(R.id.service_list_fragment, newFragment).commit();

      }
```

Main activity java code

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements TabListener, AddServiceDialogFragmentListener
, OnClickListener{

    private final String TAG = "MQTT main activity";

    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
    private ActionBar actionBar;




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Initilization
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        actionBar = getActionBar();

        List<Fragment> fragments = new Vector<Fragment>();
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, StatusListFragment.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, ServicesListFragment.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, ConfigFragment.class.getName()));

        mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),fragments);

        viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);        

        // Adding Tabs
        for (String tab_name : MqttApplication.tabs) {
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                    .setTabListener(this));
        }

        /**
         * on swiping the viewpager make respective tab selected
         * */
        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                // on changing the page
                // make respected tab selected
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
            }
        });

        // lock the screen in portrait mode
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

    }


    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


}
```

Tabs page adapter

```
public class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private List<Fragment> fragments;
    private FragmentManager fm;

    private final String TAG = "TabsPagerAdapter";


    public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm,List<Fragment> fragments) {
        super(fm);
        this.fm = fm;
        this.fragments = fragments;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int index) {

           return  this.fragments.get(index);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return this.fragments.size();
    }

    // 0 - Status, 1 Service, 2 Config (due to the order in which they have been added)
    public Fragment findFragmentByPosition(int position) {
        return fm.findFragmentByTag(
                "android:switcher:" + R.id.pager + ":"
                        + this.getItemId(position));
    }

}
```

Comment: can you please post the xml and java file that you are using to load the parent fragments? i.e. files where you have implemented fragment pager adapter

Answer (score 0):

Just an alternate solution : implemented callbacks in your code and asked your view pager to load SpecificListNotFragment when item clicked in ServiceListFragment. Have a look and try it!

```
 public class ServicesListFragment extends ListFragment  {

    private final String TAG = "ServicesListFragment";
    Button addButton = null;

    ServiceNotifRowAdapter adapter;
    ArrayList<NotifService> list = new ArrayList<NotifService>();

    private onListItemClickCallbackListener mCallback;

    public interface onListItemClickCallbackListener {
        public void replaceFragmentToServiveListNot();
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Activity parent = getActivity();
        mCallback = parent; // remember to imlement onListItemClickCallbackListener in activity else it will give error
        // some ommited code for populating adapter with list of stored subscriptions
            adapter = new ServiceNotifRowAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),list);
        setListAdapter(adapter);

    }

      @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.servicelist_fragment, container, false);

            addButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.addServiceButton);
            MainActivity m = (MainActivity) getActivity();
            addButton.setOnClickListener(m);
            return rootView;
        }

      @Override
      public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

          NotifService  item = (NotifService) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
          Log.d(TAG, "selected service " + item.getServiceURI());

            mCallback.replaceFragmentToServiveListNot();

      }
     }


     public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements TabListener, AddServiceDialogFragmentListener
, OnClickListener,onListItemClickCallbackListener {

    private final String TAG = "MQTT main activity";

    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
    private ActionBar actionBar;

    List<Fragment> fragments;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Initilization
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        actionBar = getActionBar();

        fragments = new Vector<Fragment>();
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, StatusListFragment.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, ServicesListFragment.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, ConfigFragment.class.getName()));

        mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),fragments);

        viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);        

        // Adding Tabs
        for (String tab_name : MqttApplication.tabs) {
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                    .setTabListener(this));
        }

        /**
         * on swiping the viewpager make respective tab selected
         * */
        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                // on changing the page
                // make respected tab selected
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
            }
        });

        // lock the screen in portrait mode
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

    }


    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void replaceFragmentToServiveListNot() {
        fragments.removeAll(fragments);
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, StatusListFragment.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, ServiceSpecifNotListFragment.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, ConfigFragment.class.getName()));

        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


}
```

Comment: I tried it here, but it did not work... I am wondering if somehow the FragmentPagerAdapter is keeping the old fragments alive, as I did not see any logging regarding the re-creation of the fragments, although I saw that the `replaceFragmentToServiveListNot` has been invoked