# Unable to replace fragment in viewpager

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I've been trying to replace the current fragment with another one when an item on the list view has been pressed. However when the button is pressed, the onClick method is fired but it does not replace the fragment.

**JournalFragment.java**

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_journal_view, container, false);
        context = getContext();
        ListView myView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView);

        TableControllerUser TCU = new TableControllerUser(context);
        final TableControllerJournal TCJ = new TableControllerJournal(context);


        int accID = TCU.getLoggedInId();
        Cursor cursor = TCJ.getAllJournals(accID);
        Cursor allFood = TCJ.getAllFoodJournals(accID);
        Cursor allActivity = TCJ.getAllActivityJournals(accID);
        Cursor[] cursors = {cursor, allFood, allActivity};

        MergeCursor m = new MergeCursor(cursors);

        final JournalAdapter adapter = new JournalAdapter(context, m, 0);

        myView.setAdapter(adapter);

        myView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Cursor c = (Cursor) adapter.getItem(position);
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "onClick Pressed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                String title = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("title"));

                if (title.contains("Glucose")) {
                    String glucose = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("glucose"));
                    String dateTime = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("glucose_time"));
                    String journalId = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_id"));
                    String split[] = dateTime.split(" ");
                    String date = split[0];
                    String time = split[1];

                    Fragment gluFrag = new GlucoseFragment();

                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putString("time", time);
                    bundle.putString("date", date);
                    bundle.putString("glucose", glucose);
                    bundle.putString("journalId", journalId);

                    gluFrag.setArguments(bundle);
                    ((GraphActivity) getActivity()).replaceFragments(gluFrag, bundle);
                }
           }
        });
        return rootView;
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    }

}
```

**JournalFragment.XML**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="edu.tp.sghealthapp.JournalViewFragment"
    android:id="@+id/jv">


        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView"
            android:layout_below="@+id/viewPager"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:divider="@color/iron"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**JournalListViewLayout.XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_listTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/arrowIcon"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/arrowIcon"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:typeface="sans" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/arrowIcon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**GraphActivity.java**

```
public class GraphActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Context context;
    TabLayout mTabLayout;
    ViewPager mViewPager;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        context = getApplicationContext();
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_graph);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0);


        mTabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        ViewPagerAdapter pgAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        pgAdapter.addFragments(new GraphFragment(), "Graph");
        pgAdapter.addFragments(new JournalViewFragment(), "Journal");
        mViewPager.setAdapter(pgAdapter);
        mTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);


    }

    public void replaceFragments(Fragment newFragment, Bundle bundle) {
        Fragment fragment = newFragment;
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);
        ft.replace(R.id.jv, fragment);
        ft.commit();

    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

**ActivityGraph.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context=".GraphActivity"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/graph">


    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/primary"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabMode="scrollable"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/white"
        app:tabTextColor="@color/black">
        <!--To be fixed in future to occupy whole bar when mode = fixed-->


    </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

    <edu.tp.sghealthapp.library.graphViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/tabLayout"></edu.tp.sghealthapp.library.graphViewPager>





</RelativeLayout>
```

**EDIT 2**

Tried Harron's and  Vivek_Neel's methods, both of them work but cause this problem with the formatting

[image: Messed Up Formatting]

Putting android:layout_below="@+id/viewPager" in the linearLayout causes the fragment to no longer display

**EDIT 3**

Solved the formatting problem with this https://stackoverflow.com/a/34573034/5509513

Comment: is your  if-condition executed?

Comment: Does this id exixts R.id.jv ?

Comment: @PradeepGupta the if condition is executed but the fragment transaction does not work

Comment: @Haroon R.id.jv exists in the JournalFragment.xml

Comment: Can you also post your `activity_graph.xml`

Comment: That has to be part of Activity not fragment because your method replaceFragments() is in activity

Comment: Exactly . you should have that `R.id.jvin`  in `activity_graph.xml`

Comment: @Vivek_Neel added ActivityGraph.xml

Comment: @Isaac your `activity_graph.xml` doesn't have `R.id.jv`

Comment: @Haroon So i put the 'R.i.d.jv' under the relative layout or should I make a new linear layout?

Comment: @Isaac pls check my answer. replace `activity_graph.xml` with mine

Comment: Is there any fragment which is already added before this transaction happens ?

Comment: @Haroon only the fragments already in the viewpager

Comment: It has to do with The View Hierarchy play around you should be able to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**activity_graph.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context=".GraphActivity"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/graph">


    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/primary"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabMode="scrollable"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/white"
        app:tabTextColor="@color/black">
        <!--To be fixed in future to occupy whole bar when mode = fixed-->


    </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

    <edu.tp.sghealthapp.library.graphViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/tabLayout"></edu.tp.sghealthapp.library.graphViewPager>

 <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/jv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />



</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: The fragment can be replaced but now I'm having some formatting issue:
[Link](http://i.imgur.com/iEn2LvZ.png)

Comment: @Isaac I am not able to check your link since it's blocked here in my company. Sorry :)

Comment: Oh I think the layout of Journal fragment is still behind it.? You could try to have the fragment container in journal fragment 's layout and replace it from there itself

Answer (score 2):

```
   <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/jv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Put this code snip and into activity and check

Comment: Your method and Vivek_Neel's both produce the desired effect but there is some problem with the formatting, please refer to the edit. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> Try `wrap_content` the height of `View Pager` and add `Relative Layout` with `@+id/jd` and give it `layout below view pager`.

**Refer this.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/graph"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">


    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/ColorPrimary"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabMode="scrollable"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="#FFF"
        app:tabTextColor="#000">
        <!--To be fixed in future to occupy whole bar when mode = fixed-->


    </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

    <edu.tp.sghealthapp.library.graphViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/tabLayout" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/jv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/viewPager" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

**EDIT 1**

> Second way to do it create new layout only with `Frame Layout`. And use it's Place Holder while replacing your `Fragment`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

  <FrameLayout
       android:id="@+id/jd"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent">
  </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This does not work. The new fragment will not appear on screen even though the onClick method is fired :(

Comment: It will replace and show your fragment content below view pager check it. if not wrap content then give some fix height to view pager like 100dp.

Comment: @jayDorider the fragment now appears but it appears along side the current fragment. Is there a way to completely replace the fragment?

I am already using fragmentTransaction.replace

Comment: @Isaac Check my answer EDIT 1 part try with it.

Comment: @Isaac Also i notice the id **jd** is defined twice modify with different name in `List View`  `Root Layout`.