# Android: Fragment showing from old fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have two fragments on top of each other when I call the second fragment I still the buttons from the first fragment stay visible and functional.

I tried many many methods but didn't work

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12958555/android-replace-fragment-still-displays-some-of-the-replaced-fragment) one gave me this error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0e0004 (*.test:id/customId) for fragment SecondFragment{adef947 #0 id=0x7f0e0004}

and [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12958555/android-replace-fragment-still-displays-some-of-the-replaced-fragment)

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0e00ae (sy.aya.ayaisp.test:id/gatesViewpager) for fragment SecondSFragment{adef947 #0 id=0x7f0e00ae}

my code is as follows:

> FirstFragment.java

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.first_fragment, container, false);
        Button FBtn = (Button) myView.findViewById(R.id.Fbutton);
FBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("second", "f button");
                SecondFragment secondFragment = new secondFragment();
                secondFragment.setArguments(bundle);

                FragmentTransaction ft = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_up, R.anim.slide_in_up);
                ft.replace(R.id.s_con, secondFragment).addToBackStack("back").commit();
            }
        });
```

> SecondFrag.java

```
       @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      String bundleString = this.getArguments().getString("second");
      View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.s_rv, container, false);
RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.s_recyclerview);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
if (bundleString == "agents button") {
  recyclerView.setAdapter(new SecondAdapter(getContext()));
}
}
```

> first_fragment.xml

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/s_con"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <Button
    android:id="@+id/Fbutton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="secondFragment"/>
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

> s_rv.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <sy.aya.ayaisp.ExpandableRecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/s_recyclerview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In second fragment layout "s_rv" in root element of xml add some `background`, `clickable="true"` and `focusable="true"`.

And in first fragment layout wrap your button in `LinearLayout`. two days back I was also facing same issue it was solved after that.

Comment: It's working just by putting the views in another container. can you explain why?

Comment: I was facing same issue and it was solved by doing this.

I think it is due to some hierarchy, button has precedence over fragment. 
I am just making a guess ;)

Answer (score 0):

It is because in your first fragment the id of button is "pos_agents_button" but in findViewById you are trying to find "R.id.Fbutton".

Change

```
Button FBtn = (Button) myView.findViewById(R.id.Fbutton);
```

to

```
 Button FBtn = (Button) myView.findViewById(R.id.pos_agents_button);
```

and everything should work fine.

Comment: sorry my bad but I forgot to change the ids of some resources while putting the code here, I edited it to be as the app 
Thank you