# What is the function getContentView() in PrintedPdfDocument of Android

Tags: android, printing, view

I am working on the printing custom file of Android, and I have some doubts in developer website of PrintedPdfDocument

```
// open a new document
   PrintedPdfDocument document = new PrintedPdfDocument(context,
     printAttributes);
// start a page
   Page page = document.startPage(0);
// draw something on the page
   View content = getContentView();
   content.draw(page.getCanvas());
// finish the page
   document.finishPage(page);
   . . .
```

What does the getContentView mean? I think I need to write the function body by myself, but I am not sure what is view mean? Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah. This method needs to be written unless you're working within a [PopupWindow](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html) or [GuidedActionsStylist.ViewHolder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v17/leanback/widget/GuidedActionsStylist.ViewHolder.html). These two has their own getContentView method supplied.

Basically, what this method does or intending to do is to provide you the root(or content) view of window.

Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5273436/how-to-get-activitys-content-view) if you're writing this code under an Activity and implement your getContentView accordingly. Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6925941/get-fragments-container-view-id) if you're using Fragment.

Comment: I write it in a fragment.